# Stop repeating values in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a UITableViewCell programatically with a custom UITableViewCell class, however for some reason the values are repeating inside the UILabels even though the values being read from the NSMutableArray are correct and that I am clearing these values in the prepareForReuse method of the custom UITableViewCell class.

This is what the cellForRow:AtIndexPath method looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cellDictionary = [xmlMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MatchingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.itemsDictionary = cellDictionary;
    cellDictionary = nil;
    [cell drawCell];

    return cell;   
}
```

Then inside then this is what my custom class looks like

```
#import "MatchingCell.h"
#import "ScreenSize.h"

@implementation MatchingCell

@synthesize itemsDictionary;
@synthesize nameString;
@synthesize addressString;
@synthesize codeString;
@synthesize scrollCell;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        nameString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        nameString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        addressString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        addressString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        codeString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        codeString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        scrollCell = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        scrollCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [scrollCell addSubview:nameString];
        [scrollCell addSubview:addressString];
        [scrollCell addSubview:codeString];
        [self addSubview:scrollCell];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)drawCell
{
    nameString.frame = CGRectMake(15.0, 0.5, 70.0, 40.0);
    nameString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

    addressString.frame = CGRectMake(105.0, 0.5, 95.0, 40.0);
    addressString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"Address"];

    codeString.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 10.5, codeString.frame.size.width, 50.0);
    codeString.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ISN %@: %@",[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"CodeA"] ,[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"CodeB"]];
    [codeString sizeToFit];

    scrollCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ScreenWidth, 45.0);
    [scrollCell setContentSize:(CGSizeMake((220.0 + codeString.frame.size.width)+15, 45.0))];


}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    nameString = nil;
    nameString.text = nil;
    addressString = nil;
    addressString.text = nil;
    codeString = nil;
    codeString.text = nil;

    itemsDictionary = nil;

    [self didTransitionToState:UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask];
}

@end
```

So my question is how do I stop the values repeating when you scroll new UITableViewCells into view?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take everything in init, and move it to drawCell:

You clear all of your references in prepare for reuse, but they're never recreated because of this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MatchingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

So your init only runs the first time.

The cell still exists, but none of its references to its subviews do.

Two Notes:

You should remove from subview as well in prepare for reuse, before you nil out the reference. because otherwise you'll keep adding subviews on top of subviews and you'll get bad performance.  (as suggested by @user2891327)

You shouldn't be adding views directly to the cell, use its .contentView property for subviews.

Comment: No problem, I just made a couple notes that you should see as well! Good luck.

Comment: awsome in regards to the contentView will this mean the UITableViewcell is still selectable because as it stands its not selectable anymore when I overlay the scrollview.

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  Are you saying if you add it to the contentView it's not selectable, but otherwise it is?

Comment: nope I am saying the way I have it now [self addSubView:scrollCell]; prevents the UITableViewCell from being selected. I just tried this [self.contentView addSubview:scrollCell]; and its not selectable either. I can scroll the UIScrollView in both instances but not select the UITableViewCell.

Comment: Scrollview is probably intercepting the touch, not sure exactly what the problem is, sorry.  Did you set your tableView's .allowsSelection or .allowsMultipleSelection to YES?

Comment: no i did not set that im not sure where to put it as this is my first time using a custom cell like this... will do some reading now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after dequeueing

```
 for (UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    [view removeFromSuperview];
```

If it works, it means you need to remove the subViews first.

Comment: sorry where do I try it?.. okay ill try now.

Comment: okay I added that and it deletes all of the UITableViewCells after scrolling them out of view.

Comment: After   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];